# Wrong answer within 'Calculus Solution Manual, Michael Spivak, 3rd ed'

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I have a problem with the answer provided in the solution manual of Calculus, Michael Spivak, 3rd ed,
The Problem:
Consider a hyperbola, where the difference of the distance between the two foci is the constant 2a, and choose one focus at O and the other at (-2 $\varepsilon$,0).
(In this case, we must have $\varepsilon > 1$). Show that we obtain the exact same equation in polar coordinates:
$$r=\frac{\Lambda}{1+\varepsilon cos\theta}$$
And here is the solution from the solution manual:
The distance r from (x,y) to O is given by $$r^2=x^2+y^2{} \ (1).$$
While the distance s to f is given by $$s^2=(x+2\varepsilon a)^2+y^2.$$
Now writing the condition $$r-s=2a$$ as $$r-2a=s$$ and squaring, we get the equation:$$4a^2-4ar+r^2=x^2+4\varepsilon ax+4\varepsilon^2 a^2+y^2{} \ (2)$$
so subtracting (1) equation from (2) gives:
$$a-r=\varepsilon x+\varepsilon ^2 a$$
 and thus $r=\Lambda -\varepsilon x$, for $\Lambda=(1-\varepsilon ^2)a$, then $$r=\frac{\Lambda}{1+\varepsilon cos\theta}.$$
 It remains to consider the points satisfying
 $$s-r=2a,$$
 or
 $$r+2a=s$$
 Squaring we now obtain
 $$r^2+4ar+4a^2=x^2+4\varepsilon ax+4\varepsilon ^2 a^2+y^2{} \ (\acute{2}).$$
 Subtracting  (1) from  ($\acute{2}$) gives
 $$a+r=\varepsilon x+\varepsilon ^2a,$$
 or
 $$r=(\varepsilon ^2-1) a + \varepsilon x = -(\Lambda-\varepsilon x),$$
 Which is simply the negative of the r found previously;thus, the other branch of the hyperbola is obtained by choosing $-\Lambda$ for $\Lambda$.
[image: The hyperbola]

Now I think there is something wrong. Because if $-\Lambda =\Lambda$, then 
 $$r=\Lambda + \varepsilon x \Longrightarrow r=\Lambda + \varepsilon rcos \theta \Longrightarrow r=\frac{\Lambda}{1-\varepsilon cos\theta}.$$
 And simply this is different from the formula for the other branch of the hyperbola.

Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The proof breaks down near the end.
We have $r = (\varepsilon ^2-1) a +\varepsilon x = -\Lambda + \varepsilon r cos \theta$.
It follows that $r = -\Lambda / (1 - \varepsilon  cos \theta)$. Now replace $r$ by $-r_1$ and $\theta$ by $180 + \theta_1$
to get $r_1 = \Lambda  / (1 + \varepsilon  cos \theta_1)$, which is the same as the earlier formula.

Note that the left half of the hyperbola corresponds to positive values of $r$, 
while the right half corresponds to negative ones.